# Initialize Custom UIViewController in another's UIViewController init

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have these custom UIViewController, LoadingViewController and LoadableViewController and I LoadableViewController needs to present the LoadingViewController upon the startLoading function or dismiss it upon stopLoading function. My attempt is the following but I am not sure how to declare the variable for loadingViewController in the initializer, since it is already defined in the storyboard and will be allocated by the storyboard and I don't want to double allocate it for no reason (meaning add a loadingViewController = LoadingViewController() ) in the init.

```
import UIKit

class LoadableViewController: UIViewController {

    var loadingViewController: LoadingViewController

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        loadingViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoadingiewController") as! LoadingViewController
    }

    func stopLoading() {
        loadingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func startLoading() {
        presentViewController(loadingViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all looks good to me. There should be no double allocation, as each time the view appears you will overwrite the previous assignment of `self.loadingViewController` and ARC will garbage collect the old value.

There is no need for `self.loadingViewController = LoadingViewController()`, as this instance will not know about the interface you created with `IBOutlet`s on your storyboard. When you use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, an instance of `LoadingViewController` is created with the UI elements you associated this class with within Interface Builder.

Comment: right but if i ommit the self.loadingViewController = LoadingViewController() the compiler complains that it has never been initialized, and i don't think i can do self.loadingViewController = nil. What can I do?

Comment: You can alter the line to read `var loadingViewController: LoadingViewController = nil` and it will be fine, because you always instantiate `self.loadingViewController` each time the view appears. Just make sure to only call `startLoading()` and `stopLoading()` after the view appears so you don't try to present a nil view controller.

I would actually suggest you instantiate `self.loadingViewController` in `startLoading()` and set it to nil in `stopLoading()` in order to alleviate this problem.